# Google maps Button "MyLocation"

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

Я решил реализовать кнопку "Определения местоположения" со всеми состояниями, как в Google maps.

Подробнее:

- *Неактивная* - Когда пользователь шастает по карте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- *Активная* - Когда пользователь определил свое местоположение на карте, и камера следует за ее перемещением.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Теперь к коду:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location_black_24dp"
    android:tint="@android:color/background_dark" //серый цвет т.е. неактивная изначально
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>
```

Кнопка определения местоположения:

```
FAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        cameraFromPosition();
        followUser = true;
        FAB.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.primary)); // синий цвет т.е. активная
    }
});
```

Слежка за местоположением:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (followUser) { // начинаем слежку т.к. нажата кнопка "определения местоположения" и цвет ей синий
        cameraFromPosition();
    }
}
```

Как лучше реализовать метод "*Отлова*, когда пользователь опять начал шастать по карте, и тем самым кнопку сделать неактивной т.е. серой"?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь то вы можете отловить событие скрола карты, в колбэк которого приходит булево значение, обозначающее, инициировал ли юзер это движение. Думаю это должно вашу проблему решить

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо Вам за "колбэк"! данное слово послужило отправной точкой по просторам Google:)

Comment: Пожалуйста) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Откопал я таки официальную серию новых методов от Google [[Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events#camera_change_events)], которые отлавливают *скролл* по карте и не только.

*P.S. all inclusive.*

Для решения моей задачи хватило только следующее:

1. `implements GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener`.
2. В методе `public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)`
   добавить`map.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(this);`.

И последнее:

```
@Override
public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {
    if (reason == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE) {
        followUser = false;
        FAB.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.grey));
    }
}
```

P.S. Готовый Callback от Google в подарок.

Comment: Пытаюсь реализовать подобное, но по Вашему примеру чутка не получается в силу моей неопытности, а дублировать вопрос как-то не охота, надеюсь Вы подскажете.
Добавил я вообщем все ваши изменения, но cameraFromPosition,followUser подсвечиваются красным, не могли бы вы дополнить ваш код + не очень понятно преобразования типа grey/primary вы просто прописали туда значение цвета, верно ли я понял? и пожалуй последнее, саму кнопку местоположения добавляем сами, или можно посредством map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true); ?

Comment: @Morozov cameraFromPosition - это мой метод, перед onCreate() добавьте boolean followUser. Grey и primary это цвета, которые в color.xml. Саму кнопку сами, map,getUI...(false), а не (true).